# Hungarian method variant

Tags: algorithm

I have some workers and tasks, and want to assign the best workers for each task, that's a typical use for Hungarian method.

But let's add that tasks happen at certain day/time, and I want to add in consideration that for a given worker, I'd like his tasks to be as close in time as possible.

Is there an algorithm where I could set a priority between the two different goals?

edit: let's try a simple example. I have 3 tasks happening respectively at 1:00, 2:00 and 3:00. I have 2 workers for my tasks. If I consider only the quality of the work, I assign worker 1 on slots 1 and 3, and worker 2 on slot 2. But then the 1st worker has a hole in his schedule, So I'd like to put a "weight" value so that I have an equilibrium between the total quality and the will to have compact work hours.

Thanks,
Guillaume

Comment: If a worker can't serve two tasks at the same time (not stated, but probably relevant), you are far away from the assignment-problem and this is probably NP-hard (more like a scheduling problem). And even your original task looks not much like the assignment-problem, but to be fair: it's not stated in a mathematically formal way!

Comment: I'm afraid you could be right, do you have a link that would elaborate on this class of problem? The Wikipedia article on Job shop scheduling is a bit too messy for my tastes.

Comment: There is more than job shop scheduling. If your task is similar, it's a discrete-optimization task (and most of these are NP-hard; meaning: heuristics are needed). There is a lot of material and a lot of algorithms (constraint-programming, mixed-integer programming, SAT-solving, heuristics / metaheuristics). Discrete-optimization in general and a lot of scheduling is nicely taught [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/discrete-optimization) (which i hope is still free).